# has_many record insertion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I want to insert tags in new Place. giving that tags is in different model.

```
####### models ##########
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place
  attr_accessible :tag
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end
```

how can I handle this in the new Place create form? and the create action in the places_controller? so that I can insert new place and mant tags then assign the product id to each tag.

```
####### place controller ##########

def create
  @place = Place.new(params[:place])
  @tag = Tag.new(params[:?????]) #this should be more than once

  respond_to do |format|
    if @place.save
      format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @place, status: :created, location: @place }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

####### place new form ##########
<%= form_for @place do |f| %>     
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rank %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :rank %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lat %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lat %>
  </div><div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lng %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lng %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :website %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :website %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag "tags" %>
    <%= f.text_field :tag %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to do it on your own, you should look into `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, where there's a great 2 part tutorial by Ryan Bates at [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
2. If you don't want to do it on your own, there are several tag gems available, for instance:
   [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
    <%= t.label :name %>
    <%= t.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

And in your `Place` model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
```

And in your controller, you wouldn't even have to worry about creating tags.

You should still try to read about `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, they're often useful, since your problem is very common.